# Flash Builder not supporting .jpg and .png

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

am working on flash builder 4.7, most of the jpg and png images are not publishing when i run the code. Have convert to bitmap data this case my swf file size increjing...... its taking more time to load on web.

using flash pro publishing as ".swc".

Some post the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Chandu

Comment: do you setup linkage/export for actionscript for those bitmaps when you compile the .swc  ?

Comment: before compile the flash builder, am compile the .swc

Comment: yup, that's what I meant, in flash professional before passing the compiled swc to flash builder. if I understand correctly, you are importing jpgs in flash professional, exporting a swc then using that swc in flash builder, right ? If so, it should a matter of importing the images to the library, exporting them for actionscript an compiling the swc. If you just want to use a few images, you can create a static class in flash builder and use the [Embed] metadata tag (see [example](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853)) to add your images